# Handling Unauthorised Errors in Retrofit for Asynchronous Calls

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using Retrofit for both asynchronous and synchronous api calls.

For both I have a custom error handler defined to handle unauthorised responses. For the synchronous calls I have declared the custom exception on the interface methods, I surround the interface implementation with a try/catch and it works perfect. I can catch Unauthorised Exceptions.

I have tried the same with asynchronous calls that use a callback and it doesn't work the same. Instead of the catching the Exception in the try/catch, I have to handle it in the failure method of the callback.

Here is the interface method:

```
@GET("getGardenGnomes")
void getGardenGnomes(@Header("Authorisation") String authorisation, Callback<GardenGnomes> callback) throws UnauthorisedException;
```

Here is the implementation:

```
void onClick() {
    try {
        getGardenGnomes()
    } catch (UnauthorisedException exception) {
        // .... handle the exception ....
    }
}

void getGardenGnomes() throws UnauthorisedException {
    // .... get client etc etc ....

    client.getGardenGnomes(authorisation, new Callback<GardenGnomes>() {
                @Override
                public void success(GardenGnomes gardenGnomes, Response response) {
                    // .... do something ....
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    // .... handle error ....
                }
            }
    );
}
```

The question is:

Should I just handle the exception in the failure(RetrofitError error) method of the Callback and don't declare *throws UnauthorisedException* on the interface method of asynchronous calls?

**Or what is the best way to implement this?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The anwser is yes.  Using Retrofit interfaces you don't declare which exception is thrown from the implementation on the interface.  RetrofitError is a RuntimeException therefore unchecked.  It's expected that a RetrofitError will be thrown on failures from the Retrofit implementation and you're responsible for handling it accordingly.  Using synchronous method you simply use the try/catch as you mentioned.  Using the asynchronous method you handle it in the failure callback method.

```
public void methodToHandleRetrofitError(RetrofitError error) {
    // handle the error
}

// Synchronous
try {
    client.getGardenGnomes(authorization)
} catch (RetrofitError e) {
    methodToHandleRetrofitError(e);
}

// Asynchronous
client.getGardenGnomes(authorisation, new Callback<GardenGnomes>() {
                @Override
                public void success(GardenGnomes gardenGnomes, Response response) {
                    // .... do something ....
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    methodToHandleRetrofitError(error);
                }
            }
    );
```

Hope this clarifies things for ya!

Comment: Thanks Miguel, answered perfectly.